# TypeError: handlers.push is not a function

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am using jQuery 1.9.1 version and highcharts latest version. I am trying to plot the below graph

```
$(function () {

    function drawGraph() {

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'scatter',
                renderTo: 'container'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan 2/12', 'Feb 1/12', 'Mar 1/12', 'Apr 4/12', 'May 1/12'],
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Point',
                enableMouseTracking: false,
                data: [1.75, 1.7, 2.9, 1.7, 1.7]
            }]
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        drawGraph();
    });
});
```

But I am getting this error:

> TypeError: handlers.push is not a function

Which is throwing in jquery-1.9.1.js at line 2816

Has anyone faced this issue previously? Suggestions please?

Comment: No need to put the call to `drawGraph` inside that `document.ready`... its already wrapped in `document.ready`; `$(function());` is shorthand for it.

Comment: Even though after removing "document.ready" it is still throwing same error.

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mRs9U/1/